# How do I disable cloudwatch monitoring of an instance via Ruby API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I went over all the places in the API I thought this would be possible, didn't find anything.

All these instances are in autoscale groups, I don't see in launch configs how to force this.

It would be nice if new instances simply would have this disabled.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to disable the monitor itself, but you can disable the actions.  Make sure you're using V2 of the API.

```
cloudwatch = Aws::CloudWatch::Client.new(
  region: region_name,
  credentials: credentials
)
 resp = cloudwatch.disable_alarm_actions(
      # required
      alarm_names: ["AlarmName", '...'],
    )
```